# change WooCommerce to a none commercial wish list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I designed a WooCommerce template for a customer. Now he wants to remove prices and visitors only add what they want to the list. So there will be no payment method. s: 
- I can't change plugin or database. All data must remain how they are.
- I need to remove prices from all over the site. where ever they are. Cart, wishlist, single page & etc.
- I need to change payment method to something like submit list.
- at the end after submit list page there must be a contact info page. 
 please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook into `wc_price` and remove the prices there

```
function my_filter_wc_price( $price ){
    return '';
}
add_filter( 'wc_price', 'my_filter_wc_price' );
```

Then you can hook into `parse_query` and redirect the checkout page to the contact page.

```
function my_parse_query(){
    if( is_page( wc_get_page_id( 'checkout' ) ) ){
        wp_redirect( '/contact' );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'my_parse_query' );
```

That will stop people from being able purchasing things. Just hiding the price with CSS will not. They will still be able to craft URL's to add to cart, and find the cart / checkout pages.

Comment: @Mohsen35 Don't forget to like and subscribe.... Hang on.... Wrong site....

Answer (score 0):

since I found no other way I decided to do it width CSS and translation.

I removed all prices by display:none; 
and I translated all the strings which are about shop and price.